# where to add "gunicorn hello:app --timeout 10" parameter?

Tags: heroku, deployment

I need to add Gunicorn parameter `--timeout 600`. Where should I add it? My project contains a `Procfile`, `server.py` and Jupyter notebook and `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Side note: it's rare for any Heroku question to be appropriately tagged [tag:git]. Git is about committing into repositories and sending commits around (including sending commits *into* Heroku so that Heroku can deploy them); Heroku is about making an app run; Git has nothing to do with running apps, it's just delivering the files that you've written *for* your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Procfile` defines process types for Heroku to run. Yours likely contains a line like this:

```
web: gunicorn hello:app
```

This tells Heroku that you have a `web` process that can be started by running `gunicorn hello:app`. If you want to pass an argument to `gunicorn`, modify that line accordingly:

```
web: gunicorn hello:app --timeout 600
```

Commit that change and redeploy.